# What is the meaning of this quote by Marco Tulio Cicero?

Tags: meaning

"Laudant quae sciunt,vituperant quae ignorant;laudare a bonis et vituperari a malis unun atque idem est"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about learning English. We have another site in the network, [Latin Language](http://latin.stackexchange.com/), which deals with Latin.